# How do I target only the class associated with the on(change) event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I've created a three question survey where, depending on the selected option, the user receives either more detail or an error message. I need the message to toggle on only the current form on which the event is happening. How do I target only the class associated with the current event?

```
(function() {
 $('.styled-select').on('change', function() {
    var id = $('option:selected').parent().attr('id');
    console.log(id);

    var $wrongAnswer = $(this).parent().filter('.wrong-answer');
    var $story       = $(this).parent().filter('.story');


    if ( $.inArray( $(this).val(), ['artisan', 'hipster', 'meditation', 'cardigan'] )) {
        $wrongAnswer.removeClass('expand');
        $story.addClass('expand');

    } else {
        $wrongAnswer.addClass('expand');
        $story.removeClass('expand');
    }

 });
})();
```

The HTML

```
<section id="q-three" class="survey">
<form action="">
    <select name="" id="select-three" class="styled-select" >
        <option default>Select one</option>
        <option value="artisan">artisan</option>
        <option value="humblebrag">humblebrag</option>
        <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
        <option value="kickstarter">kickstarter</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Put a bird on it kogi master cleanse try-hard salvia.</h2>

    <div class="story">
        <h3>Pickled letterpress 3 wolf moon crucifix. Migas artisan thundercats, four loko keytar chicharrones shabby chic drinking vinegar knausgaard portland street art occupy small batch. </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrong-answer">
            <h3>Try again!</h3>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/LGpzxM).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each question with a `div`, so `$wrongAnswer` and `$story` will be searched only in `div` with the current question, not in the whole form.

```
<section id="q-three" class="survey">
<form action="">
  <div>
    <select name="" id="select-three" class="styled-select" >
        <option default>Select one</option>
        <option value="artisan">artisan</option>
        <option value="humblebrag">humblebrag</option>
        <option value="brooklyn">brooklyn</option>
        <option value="kickstarter">kickstarter</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Put a bird on it kogi master cleanse try-hard salvia.</h2>

    <div class="story">
        <h3>Pickled letterpress 3 wolf moon crucifix. Migas artisan thundercats, four loko keytar chicharrones shabby chic drinking vinegar knausgaard portland street art occupy small batch. </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrong-answer">
            <h3>Try again!</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, in the script, use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`:

```
var $wrongAnswer = $(this).parent().find('.wrong-answer');
var $story       = $(this).parent().find('.story');
```